# Overwrite contents of the file in C

Tags: c, fopen, fwrite, fseek

I try to overwrite contents of the file using `fwrite()`, `fseek()` in C, but it doesn't work.

The file size is 30. I want to write "ABCD" by overwrite position 10 ~ 13 in the file. So I program below.

```
FILE *fp = fopen("file.txt", "a+");
fseek(fp, 10, SEEK_SET); 
fwrite("ABCD", 1, 4, fp);
```

But `"ABCD"` is written after position 30 in the file. I found some advice to use the binary mode (like `"ab+"`) but the `'b'` [is ignored on all POSIX conforming systems](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fopen.3.html).

How can I do this?

Comment: Why are you opening the file for "append"? The mode `"a+"`
opens for reading and appending. Use mode `"r+"`.

Comment: Oh, it works well when using `r+`. Thank you!

Comment: For streams opened in text mode, `fseek` has limited use, because carriage return–linefeed translations can cause `fseek` to produce unexpected results.

Comment: In append mode, all writes occur at the end of the file; there is no way to position the file and write at the given position (using `FILE *` functions; the rules are different, slightly, if you drop into file descriptors and use [`pwrite()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pwrite.html)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `"r+"` mode to open the file instead of `"a+"` (the `b` for binary is optional and essentially irrelevant on POSIX systems):-

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    FILE *fp = fopen("file.txt", "r+");
    fseek(fp, 10, SEEK_SET);
    fwrite("ABCD", 1, 4, fp);
    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```